# How to Generate Order List Item from List in python

Tags: python, list, flask, jinja2

I tried to create an order list item (`<ol></ol>`) from a list in python. 
My list is as following:

```
listItem = [    
            ['101','Dashboard'],
            ['102','Potential Customer'],
            ['102-01','Potential Customer Activity'],
            ['102-02','Potential Customer Report'],
            ['102-99','Potentail Customer Detail'],
            ['102-99-01','Potential Customer Detail Listing'],
            ['102-99-02','Potential Customer Follow Up'],
            ['102-99-02-01','Follow Up PAR']
        ]
```

From this list, I wish to make it as order list item according to `itemID` such as `101`,`102`,`102-01`,..etc that would like this:

```
<ol>
    <li data-itemID="101">Dashboard</li>
    <li data-itemID="102">Potential Customer
        <ol>
            <li data-itemID="102-01">Potential Customer Activity</li>
            <li data-itemID="102-99">Potential Customer Detail
                <ol>
                    <li data-itemID="102-99-01">Potential Customer Detail Listing</li>
                    <li data-itemID="102-99-02">Potential Customer Follow Up
                        <ol>
                            <li data-itemID="102-99-02-01">Follow Up PAR</li>
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    <li>
<ol>
```

I have tried my code as following:

```
from flask import *
import re

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def checkName():

    orderList = ''
    listItem = [    
                ['101','Dashboard'],
                ['102','Potential Customer'],
                ['102-01','Potential Customer Activity'],
                ['102-02','Potential Customer Report'],
                ['102-99','Potentail Customer Detail'],
                ['102-99-01','Potential Customer Detail Listing'],
                ['102-99-02','Potential Customer Follow Up'],
                ['102-99-02-01','Follow Up PAR']
            ]
    print "List Item: ",listItem
    orderList += '<ol>'
    for item in listItem:
        if item[0].find('-') > 0:
            # list has sub-list item
            orderList += '<ol>'
            orderList += '<li data-itemID=%s>'%(item[0])
            orderList += item[1]
            orderList += '</li>'
            orderList += '</ol>'
        else:
            # list has no sub-list item
            orderList += '<li data-itemID=%s>'%(item[0])
            orderList += item[1]
            orderList += '</li>'

    orderList += '</ol>'

    return render_template('home.html', orderList=orderList)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% if orderList %}
        {{ orderList | safe }}
    {% else %}
        <p>Please select a list menu</p>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

However, the generated order list is not as what I expected from above, it does not has a correct sub-order list at all. In stead, it results like this:

```
1. Dashboard
2. Potential Customer
   1. Potential Customer Activity
   1. Potential Customer Report
   1. Potentail Customer Detail
   1. Potential Customer Detail Listing
   1. Potential Customer Follow Up
   1. Follow Up PAR
```

How can I correct my code to achieve result as I expected above? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code here assumes that, while it iterates through `listItem`, every time it encounters an item with a dash in the data ID, then a new OL should be started. That's not what you want, though.

For a structure like this, I lean towards a recursive algorithm to handle the subsidiary items (which helps avoid assumptions like the one above). I don't know your edge cases, but something like this might work for you:

```
# somewhere else in your codebase, let's say utils.py

import copy


def structure_listitem(listitem):
    items = copy.deepcopy(listitem)

    if not items:
        return items

    if len(items) == 1:
        items[0].append([])
        return items

    first, rest = items[0], items[1:]

    header = first[0]
    sub_items = []
    while rest and rest[0][0].startswith(header):
        sub_items.append(rest.pop(0))

    first.append(structure_listitem(sub_items))
    return [first] + structure_listitem(rest)


def render_structured_listitem(listitem):
    if not listitem:
        return ''

    out = ['<ol>']
    for item in listitem:
        the_id, header, sublist = item
        if sublist:
            out.append('<li data-itemID="%s">%s\n%s\n</li>'
                       % (the_id, header, render_structured_listitem(sublist)))
        else:
            out.append('<li data-itemID="%s">%s</li>'
                       % (the_id, header))

    out.append('</ol>')
    return '\n'.join(out)


def render_listitem(listitem):
    return render_structured_listitem(structure_listitem(listitem))
```

and then, in the app code:

```
from utils import render_listitem # or from wherever

# ...

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def check_name():
    listitem = [    
                ['101','Dashboard'],
                ['102','Potential Customer'],
                ['102-01','Potential Customer Activity'],
                ['102-02','Potential Customer Report'],
                ['102-99','Potentail Customer Detail'],
                ['102-99-01','Potential Customer Detail Listing'],
                ['102-99-02','Potential Customer Follow Up'],
                ['102-99-02-01','Follow Up PAR']
    ]    

    ordered_list = render_listitem(listitem)

    return render_template('home.html', ordered_list=ordered_list)
```

Comment: Apologies--my initial response used python 3, but I see you're using python 2. I've revised it to work in python 2.

Comment: thanks you very much, I tested your answer it really worked great with main item, sub-list and many level of sub-list!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind to go with a not well formed HTML (I am not closing the `<ol>` you can have this solution.
To have a fully compliant HTML a little work in the same direction would be needed.

## flask_file.py

```
from flask import *
import re

app = Flask(__name__)


itid = lambda x: x[0]
itval = lambda x: x[1]
last = lambda x: x[-1]

def wrapit(it_id):
    return '<li item-id="%s">' % it_id

def wrapval(id_val):
    return '%s</li>' % id_val

def put_ol(it_id):
    return last(it_id.split('-')) == '01'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def checkName():
    listItem = [
                ['101','Dashboard'],
                ['102','Potential Customer'],
                ['102-01','Potential Customer Activity'],
                ['102-02','Potential Customer Report'],
                ['102-99','Potentail Customer Detail'],
                ['102-99-01','Potential Customer Detail Listing'],
                ['102-99-02','Potential Customer Follow Up'],
                ['102-99-02-01','Follow Up PAR']
            ]
    orderItem = []

    for item in listItem:
        if put_ol(itid(item)):
            orderItem.append('<ol>')
        orderItem.append(wrapit(itid(item)))
        orderItem.append(wrapval(itval(item)))

    print("List Item: %s " % listItem)

    return render_template('home.html', orderItem=orderItem)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

## home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<ol>
{% for item in orderItem %}
        {{ item | safe }}
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```